# I can't validate the files extension in javascript/js. Could someone tell me what the error is and how to fix it?

Tags: javascript

The following code does not recognize the extensions of the files that I try to enter, which leads to always getting the "It is not a valid file" alert. I can't find the error, can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

This code is from JavaScript.

```
const dropArea = document.querySelector(".drop-area");
const dragText = dropArea.querySelector('h2');
const button = dropArea.querySelector("button");
const input = dropArea.querySelector("#input-file");
let files;

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    input.click();
});

input.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    files = this.files;
    dropArea.classList.add("active");
    showFiles(files);
    dropArea.classList.remove("active");
});

dropArea.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dropArea.classList.add("active");
    dragText.textContent = "Suelta para subir los archivos";
});

dropArea.addEventListener("dragleave", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dropArea.classList.remove("active");
    dragText.textContent = "Arrastra y suelta archivos";
});

dropArea.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    showFiles(files);
    dropArea.classList.remove("active");
    dragText.textContent = "Arrastra y suelta archivos";
});

function showFiles(files) {
    if (files.lenght === undefined) {
        processFile(files);
    } else {
        for (const file of files) {
            processFile(file);
        }
    }
}

function processFile(file) {
    const docType = file.type;
    const validExtensions = ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/gif"];

    if (validExtensions.includes(docType)) {
        //Archivo valido.
    } else {
        //No es archivo valido.
        alert('No es un archivo valido');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example `docType` that is inputted?

Comment: `files.lenght` will always be undefined because the property is spelled `length`... Because of that `processFile` is called with the array of files, and `file.type` is undefined. All of this should be discoverable by using the debugging tools in your browser.

Comment: Assuming your `files` parameter in `showFiles(files)` is an array, the `if (files.lenght === undefined)` never matches, e.g. always goes to `else`. It should be ` if (files.lenght === 0)`, or simply ` if (!files.lenght)`. Then why call `processFile(files)` if there are no files? To debug, add a `console.log(file)` in your `processFile()` function.